# Windows Forms WebBrowser control and iframes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iframe, browser

I am trying to create a piece of software to more or less automate form-fillings on a webpage - and I have decided to use the WebBrowser control in `System.Windows.Forms`. This works great and I can easily manipulate the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) through `webbrowser.Document` and so forth. However unfortunately the site that I am doing automation on has a file upload which is ran inside an iframe - and this is where I am stuck, I simply cannot work out how to be able to manipulate elements inside the DOM of the iframe.

Ideally what I'd like to do is something like:

```
HtmlElement iframe = browser.Document.GetElementById("iframe_id");
iframe.InnerDocument.GetElementById("file_upload_input").SetAttribute("value", "myfile.txt");
```

And then submit the form inside the iframe of course - however there is no `InnerDocument` attribute on `HtmlElement` as far as I can see, nor no type that I have found that I can cast `HtmlElement` to so that I can access the inner DOM.

How this is done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the "frames" collection instead.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535258(VS.85).aspx#):

> The iframe element functions as a
>   document within a document, or like a
>   floating frame. The frames collection
>   provides access to the contents of an
>   iframe. **Use the frames collection to
>   read or write to elements contained in
>   an iframe.** For example, the syntax for
>   accessing the backgroundColor style of
>   the body object in an iframe is:
>
> sColor =
>   document.frames("sFrameName").document.body.style.backgroundColor;

Comment: Aha - that was something I had forgotten. One thing to note here though is that the code you posted here is javascript - the corresponding code needed for the WebBrowser control is browser.Document.Window.Frames["frame"] to get the iframe element.

Comment: @kastermester there is no .Window under browser.document (just checked under live object) and the above code doesn't work (in VB6 anyway). is there a difference between .frames[...] and .frames(...)  ?? so ( or [ make a difference? ive tried both to no avail.

Comment: Hi, What if iframe doesn't have a name property?