# Find a link inside iframe in webbrowser control in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to find a url webbrowser control inside iframe.

1) my webbrowsercontrol opena  url 
2)that url has one iframe inside it
3) That Iframe has a link which I want to grab programmatically using vb.net

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435172/windows-forms-webbrowser-control-and-iframes

Answer (score 0):

At any point of time use webBrowser1.Url.ToString() to get the URL of the current open link.
 You can get the html code of the open url by using webBrowser1.DocumentText. Once you have the html code use string manipulation to find the "iframe src" value.

This can be abit complicated as you migt not know how may iframes you need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

As well there are some limitations for the FRAME elements according to [HtmlWindow.WindowFrameElement Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.windowframeelement.aspx)

> You cannot access a FRAME elements or the FRAME's document if the
>   FRAME is in a different zone than the FRAMESET that contains it. For a
>   full explanation, see [About Cross-Frame Scripting and Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028.aspx).

Comment: They can be bypassed, the cross frame security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you need to do is this...

Msgbox Webbrowser1.document.frames(0),getelementbyid("linkTagId").href

This will show you the href of the link, don't bother wasting time with string manipulation.

Of course, you can loop through the frames and links as well using the .length properties in a for loop.

Also, there are ways to bypass the cross-frame security issues since you are running the code in an exe, there are examples online, just search for "bypass cross-frame security webbrowser control" in google without the quotes.

If you need more help with these let me know as I can tell you how. Remember the cross frame stuff only need bypassing if the parent domain name and iframe domain name are different (not subdomains though, they can be different no problems).

Let me know mate :)