# Automate login to chase.com - Using Webbrowser Control

Tags: javascript, java, html, vb.net

**Summary of Problem**

*- A bit of a long question as I wish to provide all of the things I tried and make it easier for anyone attempting to provide a solution so please bear with me-*

In general I get the idea of some methods to automate logging in to a website using the Web browser control. I inspect the page using Chrome and find element names, ids, tags, etc and then try to find a particular control like a textbox then I can set the value property to be what I want. This works fine for most websites however Chase's has be stumped.

**First Attempt**

Here is the page inspected from Chrome:

[image]

The last line that is highlighted is the username textbox, the one I am aiming to set.

If I loop through all controls using this:

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = webbrowser.Document.All

    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.Id <> "" Or curElement.Name <> "" Then
            MsgBox(curElement.Id & ":" & curElement.Name)
        End If
    Next
```

the only relevant item found is **logonDialog** (not **userId** or **userId-input-field**).

**Second Attempt**

Now I can see in the tree that there is a hierarchy so I tried using the .Children property of the control I found:

```
    Dim logonDialog As HtmlElement = webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("logonDialog")

    For i = 0 To logonDialog.Children.Count - 1
        MsgBox(logonDialog.Children(i).Id & ":" & logonDialog.Children(i).Name & ":" & logonDialog.Children(i).TagName)
    Next
```

[image]

This results in showing **logonbox** so that is promising...

Now if I try the same method underneath the code where I found **logonbox**:

```
 Dim logonDialog As HtmlElement = webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("logonDialog")
    Dim logonbox As HtmlElement = logonDialog.Children("logonbox")
    MsgBox(logonbox.Id)
    MsgBox(logonbox.Children.Count)
    For i = 0 To logonbox.Children.Count - 1
        MsgBox(logonbox.Children(i).Id & ":" & logonbox.Children(i).Name & ":" & logonbox.Children(i).TagName)
    Next
```

It says that **logonbox** has no children... so how can I go down further? Looking at the picture shown above, is this because the next "child" in the list is "#document"?

**Third Attempt**

Using the "iFrame" approach suggested in the comments:

```
    Dim logonbox As HtmlElement = logonDialog.Children("logonbox")


    For Each element_ As HtmlElement In logonbox.Document.All
        MsgBox(element_.Id & ":" & element_.Name)
    Next
```

The list is identical to the list created in my "First Attempt"

*- Perhaps there is another completely different way to login to Chase. That is my end goal so if someone has a different way, I am open to that as well!*

Comment: Do you want it via script only or just in-browser solution will work ?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me I want a solution that can be done within the VB.NET environment. Perhaps scripting methods may shed light to a solution but end game needs to be in VB .NET

Comment: Not dupey enough, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435172/windows-forms-webbrowser-control-and-iframes) will fix not being able to access the `iframe`:

Comment: @AFriend Interesting and may save me a step or two but that still only brings me to the "logonbox" control and I would have to go deeper down the tree somehow

Comment: From your question it seems that the only trouble you're having here is that `iframe` has no `Children`.

Comment: @AFriend That is correct

Comment: The linked question provides a way to access the elements within `iframe` so you can resume using your `.Children` approach

Comment: @EricF then I want to suggest that you checkout iMacro Firefox plugin. There record macro for login to site, and then check steps the plugin follows. I hope it will help to shed some light.

Comment: @AFriend So if I try to make a loop for all html elements under the iframe one, the list is identical to all items in the original. See my question update. My iframe id is "logonbox"

Comment: @shyammakwana.me I just installed the iMacros addon. It does **not** automatically fill out the login information after recorded. It does work for other sites, just not Chase. Seems chase does something different than other sites

Comment: Gotcha! This is different case then. Try checking in network tab in chrome and see if you can replicate that request via script, this will not work in some cases (if they are using csrf token, etc )

Comment: @shyammakwana.me I can't or at least I don't know how to that way as I come to a similar road block as the question here

Comment: @EricF that's not a big deal actually, with the help of powerful chrome developer tools, you can copy request as curl request and then replicate same logic in language of your choice. If you aren't familiar with web technologies this will be like alien to you. But In reality it isn't that hard.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me Do you have a good example of how to do this? I am not familiar with using Chrome to make scripts. Could you please show how you would do so with Chase? If you post it as an answer and it works, I will definitely accept it

Comment: It's not solid solution. Ok, I'll try if it will work with chase or not. And post a script , still you have to write same logic in vb.net, I don't have account on chase even

Comment: @shyammakwana.me I really appreciate your effort! Regardless if you have an account or not, the inputting to the text fields should be identical to see if they actually populate.